# markers doesn't show on the google map API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

i am using PHP & MYSQL on wordpress in order to retrieve data from the database that contains coordinates and display markers on the Google Map.

Google Map is shown but without any markers and i did not found the error in my PHP code.

## code

```
     <?php
            /*
            Template Name: MAP2
            */

            get_header();
      ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Custom Markers</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******&callback=initMap">
        </script>

CSS CODE 
========


    <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 600px;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>

   HTML code & javascript
=========================


 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

     var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };

        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        }

        var features = [

PHP code
========


    <?php
              global $wpdb;
                $prependStr ="";
                foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT siteID, latitude, longitude FROM site_coordinates2", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
                   $latitude = $row->latitude;
                   $longitude = $row->longitude;
                   $info = $row->siteID;
               echo $prependStr;
           ?>
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
        type: '<?php echo $info; ?>'
    }
    <?php
    $prependStr =",";
    }
    ?>
            ];

            for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
              addMarker(feature);
            }
    }

             </script>


      </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: There may be no error becouse it doesnt find the icon. ` icon: icons[feature.type].icon, `

Comment: @H.Brendan so how to fix this error ? 
i comment the type and remove from **feature.type** but still nothing is working

Comment: I presume the marker doesnt know what the position is. try ` position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.727681,4.9574324),` manually - just try putting in your coordinates and not get it out of the database. if it works hard coded its something with the database tags

Comment: @H.Brendan i tried your answer it did not work i replaced the PHP code in the position with a lat lng but it did not show any marker

Comment: ok my last guess on this. `marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(DATABASE VALUE LAT, DATABASE VALUE LNG),
        map: map`                                                          and then its up to you to put in the latitude and longitude into this

Comment: @H.Brendan as you said  in the first comment it was the problem in icon  after i removed the icon the markers showed up with the regular icon .
now i need to make an info windows that display some info on a click listner.

Comment: ah ok i thought so initially but thought u said it wasnt the problem hihi but nice. and the info window should not be that hard.

Comment: @H.Brendan can you write your comment as an answer in order to up-vote

Comment: I put it in an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be no error becouse it doesnt find the icon. `icon: icons[feature.type].icon,` so try to look into that.

happy i could help.

Comment: i will open another question about the info window because i tried and it seams not working

Comment: uhm u can close this one by clicking the hook you should do that. otherwise stack will go mayham on "u have to many open questions"

Comment: and ill try to help with the info window so go ahead and open new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the locations variable.

```js
 var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need to retrieve data from the database not these value that i generate